# Group access to a particular directory

Tags: linux

I have a group called optaccess..Now, I need to give access to a directory /opt/sw/vam for this group - optaccess.

How can I do that in Linux?

I tried this

```
sudo chmod g+rwx *.*
```

but that does not work?

Where do I specify the group name - optaccess?

Answer (score 3):

You need to run **chgrp** command. Try

```
chgrp -R optaccess /opt/sw/vam
```

Note: Add "-R" only , if you want to change group of all files + **subdirectories**.

**chgrp**: This command is used to change group of any directory. 
**chmod**: This command is used to provide: read, write, access to any user/group. 
**chown**: This command is used to change user and/or group of any directory.
For ex:

```
chown -R foo:optaccess /opt/sw/vam
```

Comment: I did that and when I do ls -al...now the group is listed as optaccess but the user is listed as "root"...it should it be either (ubuntu/apacheuser) which is part of the group

Comment: So, run **chown** command as shown above..
Also in Ubuntu, the dafault user for apache is **"www-data"**, if you have not changed it..

Comment: Thanks..If i set sudo chown -R www-data:optaccess /opt/sw/vam...only www-data gets access not the other user "ubuntu"..how do I set both the user to get access

Comment: chown -R foo:optaccess /opt/sw/vam..Here I use one user...but I want to set to the group, so both user can get access...How can I do that

Comment: So, you need to add user **"ubuntu"** under the group **"optaccess"** by following command: **sudo usermod -a -G optaccess ubuntu** and then give permissions to users.